# concatenate columns from multiples files

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm using the code below to read column number 2 from approx. 5000 files and then output a matrix (NxL) where

```
N = number of files

L = number of lines (identical for all the files=600000 lines)
```

such as the format:

```
filename1 filename2 filename3 ... filename5000
file1.col2 fiel2.col2 file3.col2 ... fiel5000.col2
...
```

Here's the code I am using:

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
### module load python/2.7.8 ####
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class Backpack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inside = []
    def add(self, toadd):
        self.inside.append(toadd)
    def addmany(self, listtoadd):
        self.inside += listtoadd
    def __str__(self):
        return ', '.join(str(i) for i in self.inside)

pack = Backpack()

def concatenate(path):
        outfile="matrix.dat"
        f=open(outfile,'ab')
        np_array_list = []
        inside = []
        fileList=glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt'))
        for filename in fileList:
                        base=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
                        inside.append(base)
                        df=pd.read_table(filename,usecols=[1],header=None)
                        np_array_list.append(df.as_matrix())
        inside.append('\n')
        comb_np_array = np.column_stack(np_array_list)
        f.write(' '.join(inside))
        np.savetxt(f,comb_np_array,fmt='%d')
        f.close()
concatenate('.')
```

How to improve this code?

Comment: I guess, nobody can see a question here, so you will not get any answers either... Please be more precise with the description of your problem.

Comment: I improved tne formatting and text, although I couldn't find a question being asked...

Comment: the code is not complete, this is the complete code:

Comment: please fix your code formatting